# Why do downloaded KB different in Firefox DevTools vs. Firebug or Chrome DevTools?

Tags: firebug, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Can anyone explain me why, debugging on any page, I see always a great difference between the Firefox DevTools, Firebug and the Chrome DevTools in terms of transferred file sizes? For example, with the homepage of Stack Overflow I see:

- Chrome DevTools: 282 KB
- Firebug: 246 KB
- Firefox DevTools: 873 KB

What is the truth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In opposite to the Chrome DevTools' *Network* panel and Firebug's *Net* panel the summary within the *Network* panel of the Firefox DevTools displays the [size of the contents **after** decompression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Network_request_fields). That means it displays the actual size of the files, not the transferred bytes of the files.

Background: Some servers compress the response contents before they sent them to the client using algorithms like [GZIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) to save network bandwidth. The clients then decompress the contents once they received them.

The Firefox DevTools do not offer a summary of the transferred size of files (as of Firefox 38.0.1). The *Network* panel only displays the **decompressed** size of files at the bottom of the panel:

[image: Summary of network requests within the Network panel]

Therefore I created an [enhancement request to display the transferred size](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1168376) within the summary and the performance analysis.

Though the panel has a *Transferred* column listing the transferred size for each file:

[image: Transferred column within Firefox DevTools Network panel]

Comment: Sorry but Firefox DevTool offers the summary of KB received in the bottom bar!
In addition, clicking on "## requests ### kB.." you are able to see a pie chart about cache management related downloaded files. A very useful feature..
Beyond this, show compressed or decompressed file size explains the reason for the difference. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that I was referring to the bottom bar and the performance analysis (the pie chart). Both show only the decompressed size, not the size that was actually transferred. I extended my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where Chrome DevTools indicates 112 KB as the size for a JPEG that is actually 505 KB large (which Firefox Devtools now lists as both  transferred and size). GZIP compression can't account for this, since it won't help already compressed image files: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/gzipped-images-is-it-worth

Answer (score 4):

There are so many things at play here that contribute to the network traffic.

**1) The browsers do in fact implement different download strategies.**

As a very simplified example consider the case where you reference an image multiple times:

```
<img src="someImage">
<div style="background-image:url('someImage');">
```

The simplest possible method would be to load the image every single time. This is wasting bandwidth, which results in a bad user experience. Instead we could detect that this is the same image and just download it once.

Or better yet, we could cache it, and remember the last time we fetched an image from that server with that name, and thus show that instead. To allow the web developers to update their images we need to exchange some HTTP headers with server ensuring that the image cache we have is actually up to date.

And what if the site uses third party hosted stuff.
Can we cache that? And what to do when we visit another site that uses that same third party material?

**2) Web developers and their tricks**

So let's play a game of optimization. Say I need the site to do something in IE and Chrome, but the differences in the rendering engines make it a pain to create cross-browser layouts that just look fantastic in both...

I can hack the CSS to work in both browsers, but really, I could also simply create a layout file for each browser, and modify them independently.
I.e. http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml

Unless the browser is stupid it will recognize the optimization and only fetch the layout files that it needs instead of all the available layout files.
*This also goes for JavaScript files.*

Some browsers support stuff, and that stuff makes it easier to do fancy tricks. For the browsers that doesn't support it you need more code or a plugin like Flash or Silverlight or something else. You don't want to make the user that picked the "right" browser suffer, so you add optimizations.

**3) Endless problems answering**
The aforementioned tricks are used by advertising systems. And if you are lucky, all the third party stuff uses them. Some host jQuery, some reference Google's online hosted versions of libraries or similar.

For websites that show third party content, notice that the advertisements can contain code or differently sized images (in bytes).

Also note that the downloaded number of bytes may also refer to different things. It could show what was actually transferred, but it could also show what *would have been* transferred if we didn't use a cache.

Comment: I understand that different browsers implies different css, plugin, image, cache and so on management, but my question was focused on why Firefox debugger gave results 2/3 times higher than FireBug-Chrome (who always have very similar values)..
If I have to develop a page whose total size cannot exceed 200 KB for example, which is then the most reliable indicator? Or which tool is best to use?

Comment: the most reliable indicator is the serverside.

Comment: what do you mean? How can I get the exact page size from a webserver (obviously without sum every css-js-image-html file size involved in the page) ?

Comment: I would let the webserver monitor the outgoing traffic, assuming you have a linux machine, try using ntop.